# How can I access JQuery ($) from a template in Symfony 6 with Encore?

Tags: symfony, webpack-encore

How can I access JQuery $ from a template? I am able to access it in `app.js`, but `$` is not defined when I try to run the code in a template.

> mypage:480 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I'm using Symfony 6 with Encore installed.

`app.js`

```
...
const $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
// test code
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('success from app.js');
})
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
...
 .autoProvidejQuery()
```

`webpack_encore.yaml`

```
...
  script_attributes:
        defer: true
```

`base.html.twig` (my page template's parent)

```
...
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

My page template:

```
...
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script>
      // THIS CODE TRIGGERS THE ERROR
      $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('success from template!');
      })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What error is the error message received when you remove your test code in app.js?

Comment: are you calling `encore_entry_script_tags` in your parent template and setting this config `script_attributes.defer` to false in your webpack_encore.yaml ?

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant I get the same error when the code in app.js is commented out.

Comment: @zizoujab yes, thanks for pointing out the related detail that was missing. I updated the post to include this detail.

Comment: I had the same error because of defer is true

Comment: Did you force a rebuild after each update of webpack.config.js? ( yarn run encore... )

Comment: @zizoujab apologies, in my haste to add that config to the post, I missed the suggestion to set defer to false until I saw hous's comment. Setting defer to false fixes this. Thank you all for helping.

Comment: @Coder1 I will be posting an answer then, please accept it, it will be useful if next people who got the same issue don't have to go through comments to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be sure that you have `defer` to `false` in your encore config component:

```
# config/packages/webpack_encore.yaml
webpack_encore:
    # ...
    script_attributes:
        defer: false
```

Source : https://symfony.com/doc/6.0/frontend/encore/legacy-applications.html